# Magento Payment Module: Getting All Items in Cart

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway

I'm creating a Payment Gateway Module on Magento 1.8
In my Model code I'm trying to build a string in the correct format ready for a SOAP request.

I need to collect the order products and I'm using the below code:

```
$order_string = "";
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $order_string .= "prod=" . $item->getName() . ",item_amount=" . $item->getPrice() . 'x' . $item->getQty() . ';';
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the `$items` variable is always empty.
I've tried many variations of getting this information:

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getAllItems();
$items = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAllItems();
$items = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getAllItems();
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

etc.

If I try and `Mage::log` any of this information, I'm faced with the error:

```
User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /Users/[Username]/Sites/[Site Name]/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3865
```

If I use `->getItemsCount();` as the suffix instead of `getAllItems()` or `getAllVisibleItems()` I appear to be correctly returning the number of items.

I would just like to return an array of items, but really, all I need is the name, price and quantity, so if there's an alternative method of returning that information, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue, just now.

```
$cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getShortDescription();
    echo $item->getPrice();
    echo $item->getSku();
    echo $item->getQty();
}
```

Found at:
http://www.kathirvel.com/magento-custom-attributes-of-products-in-the-cart/

If doesn't work, then it's your event that is letting you down. If you run it through a controller, works perfectly.

Using Magento Community version 1.9.0.1